# Is there more than one answer to trig identities? Can the answer be both a pythagorean identity and a double angle?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I struggle with trig identities. It always seems that I make the wrong choices on the final step.

For example: Will it be a Pythagorean identity or a double angle identity? Is there a principle I'm missing? Here is an example:
$$h(u) =\frac{\sin x+\cos x}{\sin x-\cos x}$$ We are supposed to find the first derivative. The final step I got to was: $$\frac{-2\sin^2x-2\cos^2x}{(\sin x-\cos x)^2}$$. I decided to use the double angle identity to make it -$$\frac{2\cos2x}{(\sin x-\cos x)^2}$$ The answer given is $$\frac{-2}{(\sin x-\cos x)^2}$$. Was I wrong and what am I missing?

Comment: Did you mean $h(x) = \dfrac{\sin x + \cos x}{\sin x - \cos x}$?

Comment: You cannot have $-2\sin^2(x)-2\cos^2(x)=2\cos2x$ because the double angle formula is $\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)=\cos(2x)$ (with a plus and a minus sign)

Comment: Note:  $-2\sin^2 x - 2\cos^2 x = -2(\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x)\ne 2\sin^2 x-2\cos^2 = 2(\sin^2x - \cos^2 x)$.  So the double angle identity $(\sin^2x -\cos^2 x)=2\cos 2x$ does not apply.  Whatever identity you use will have to use $\sin^2 x +\cos^2 x$.... Fortunately perhaps that is the *most* well known trig identity of them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the numerator of your derivative is $-2(\cos^2x+\sin^2x)$, which does indeed simplify to $-2$. It seems you mistook the numerator for $-2(\cos^2x-\sin^2x)$ (which would simplify to $-2\cos 2x$), which is an understandable typo-level mistake.

For your general question, there's no hard and fast rule for when you will need/want to use particular identities; it all depends on the goal of your computations and the specific opportunities you see.

Comment: Ok I get it. Thank you so much. Identities are very frustrating. It's a totally different dialect in math. It's really hard to "get".

Comment: Frustration is understandable—just remember, new and challenging doesn't mean bad! Like everything in life, the more you practice thoughtfully, the better you'll get.

Answer (score 1):

A list of the main basic trig formulae is provided below. Learning them so well you know them in your sleep is ideal :)

$$\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x = 1$$
$$1+\tan^2 x=\sec^2 x$$
$$1+\cot^2 x=\csc ^2 x$$
$$\sin(A\pm B)=\sin A\cos B \pm\sin B \cos A $$
$$\cos(A\pm B)=\cos A \cos B \mp \sin A \cos B $$
$$\tan(A\pm B)=\frac{\tan A \pm \tan B}{1\mp \tan A \tan B}$$
$$\sin 2x =2\sin x \cos x$$
$$\cos 2x=\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x=2\cos^2 x-1 =1-2\sin^2 x$$
$$\tan 2x=\frac{2\tan x}{1-\tan^2 x}$$